# How to call a function from a UserControl from a button on the main form c#

Tags: c#

I have a main Form with a user control and when a press a panel on the user control an image is shown. I want to make a button on the main form and when i press it, the image that appeared before to hide again(as it is when the user control initialize for the first time)

I Have created a class(this is part of the project) in the user control and inside of it i created a function to hide the images (if they have appeared).
The following code didn't show errors but it didn't work.
could you please help me?

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
        }

        private void button_reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl_axi user_ax = new UserControl_axi();
            UserControl_axi.Rst_userControl.Rst_Axi(user_ax);
```

```
public class Rst_userControl 
        {
            public static void Rst_Axi(UserControl_axi rst)
            {
                rst.pictureBox5.Hide();
                rst.pictureBox6.Hide();
           }
        }
```

Comment: You pass in a newly created UserControl_axi which you never have shown.

Comment: You are creating a new user control instead of getting the one that was created by the designer on Form1.

Comment: @o_weisman how to get the one that was created and pass that to the function to hide the images?

Comment: You should find its name in the designer or by browsing into the ```InitializeComponent``` method

Comment: @OlivierDepriester in the designer the only related I found was `private user_controls.UserControl_axi userControl_axi1;` how to pass this to method?  
I am sorry for the questions but I am new to programming

Comment: Either you pass ```this.userControl_axi1``` to your current method or you apply the changes I suggested in my answer. I edited the code to use this.userControl_axi1

Comment: I did what you said  and I only changed this 
`UserControl_axi.Rst_userControl.Rst_Axi(this.userControl_axi1);   and it worked!!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, something seems strange to me : why do you create an other usercontrol in your button action ? It is not the one you may see when your form is loaded because this one is created in your method and then deleted after it has completed.
You must have another `UserControl_axi` variable/instance in your form and this is the one you have to use as an argument in the `Rst_Axi` method

```
private void button_reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // New user control user_ax ???? -> To be removed
    UserControl_axi user_ax = new UserControl_axi();
    // Changes applied to an "invisible" user_ax -> Argument to be replaced with the property of your Form of type UserControl_axi
    UserControl_axi.Rst_userControl.Rst_Axi(user_ax);
    // After this user_ax will be destroyed
}
```

Furthermore, if your `Rst_userControl` class has no other use than declaring the `Rst_Axi` method I suggest you drop it and declare directly `Rst_Axi()` as a method of `UserControl_axi`. Because the way you are doing it is overkill :)

```
public partial class UserControl_axi
{
    // Not static anymore 
    public void Rst_Axi()
    {
         // No arguments because pictureBox5 and pictureBox6 are properties of the current usercontrol
         this.pictureBox5.Hide();
         this.pictureBox6.Hide();
    }
}
```

And call

```
private void button_reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Use the property in your form related to the UserControl_axi and call its reset method
     this.userControl_axio1.Rst_Axi();
}
```

Comment: In the main form I haven't any instance/variable of `UserControl_axi`. I have 4 user controls and I use `UserControl_axi.BringToFront();` to make them appear. I don't know what to pass as an argument to the method

Comment: @christos it's quite straightforward. If you have 4 `UserControl_axi` then pass the one you brought to front to your `Rst_Axi` method. For example if you call `UserControl_axi123.BringToFront()` then to hide the pictures call `Rst_userControl.Rst_Axi(UserControl_axi123)` inside your button click event

Comment: `private void button_reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rst_Axi(userControl_axi1);` I did this and `Rst_Axi` becomes red and says "The name Rst_Axi" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I have changed the class and method to this

`public class Rst_userControl : UserControl_axi
{
public void Rst_Axi()
{
this.pictureBox5.Hide();
this.pictureBox6.Hide();
}`